# Validation Fail - Unchecks Wiki/Email

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-wiki, email, validation

To reproduce:

- Click Ask Question on meta
- Fill in question
- Check **community wiki** & **Notify [] daily of any new answers**
- Don't enter any of the required tags, causing a prompt

Result:

- Error prompt:

  > Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
  >   must include one of these tags -- bug feature-request discussion support
- community wiki and Notify [] daily of any new answers are **unchecked**

Expected:

- Error prompt
- **Options remain checked**

Suggestion:

Leave something like the content of the prompt on the page to begin with:

Tags must include at least one of: **bug**, **feature-request**, **discussion**, **support**

Comment: Not reproducible with Firefox 3.5.3

Comment: Happens in both Chrome 4.0.213.1 and Firefox 3.5.3 here

Comment: This bug bit me again today. (Chrome 5.0.335.0 dev)

Comment: I'm getting this as well, rather annoying as validation failed about 5 times for my question (stupid me).  Using Chrome 4.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed - this will be deployed this evening.

Comment: Are you sure this has been deployed? I see still see this, also on the Beta sites of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Marcel you're seeing this when asking a question?

Comment: Yes, I just tried; when submission fails, the checkboxes are cleared.

Comment: I just hit it this bug (although on the UI QA Site). I use Chrome 6.0.427.0 dev. Also I didn't tick community wiki, just notify.

Comment: @Iain - we're pushing a fix for the notify checked bug.