# Community Wiki checkbox reset on question submission error

Tags: bug, community-wiki, user-interface, posting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Validation Fail - Unchecks Wiki/Email](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24090/validation-fail-unchecks-wiki-email)

On a question error, such as:

> **Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:**
>
> - must include one of these tags -- bug feature-request discussion support

Or

> **Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:**
>
> - 'faq ' contains a tag reserved for moderator use

the community wiki checkbox is cleared.

Steps to reproduce:

1. `Ask Question`
2. Enter title and body
3. Select the `community wiki` checkbox (below body on lower left)
4. Enter tags with an error (include `faq` if you are not a moderator, or don't include a required tag)
5. `Post Your Question`
6. Observe that the title, body, and tags are intact, but the `community wiki` checkbox has been cleared

I don't know all the posting errors that can occur, but expect that if the post fails for some other reason (missing title/body, too short, ???) it may have the same issue.

Minor error, but I still see people posting questions, then indicate later that they thought they checked CW, but they had to go back later and re-check it because it obviously didn't go through.  This might be one of the root causes for that situation.