# Can't get a question to post because of tag issue

Tags: support, tags

Trying to post a question but the tag field empties everything I put into it, and I put in suggested tags when it wouldn't accept 'r'.

Comment: Browser? OS? Screenshot?

Comment: Windows 7, Firefox and I get to the robot page before it 'erases' what I put in the tag field.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24090/validation-fail-unchecks-wiki-email It's about Meta, but if you're hitting the validation page it could be the same problem.

Comment: I'll try it, thanks. I've gotten my question answered so I'll have to try it later when I have a fresh question.