# Checkbox "community wiki" gets reset if answer can't be submitted

Tags: bug, answers, user-interface, community-wiki

This is almost the same bug as the one described in [Validation Fail - Unchecks Wiki/Email](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24090/validation-fail-unchecks-wiki-email) (which is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)), but for answers.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Open any answerable question.
2. Put "Yes" in the text area, mark the community wiki checkbox, and click "Post Your Answer."
3. You get the following error message.

   > Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:
   >
   > - only Joel Spolsky can post answer with less than 30 characters; you entered 3
4. The community wiki checkbox was reset in the process.

If you just fix your answer and post it again, it won't be Community Wiki. This is clearly unexpected behavior, and it can have unpleasant consequences if overlooked.

Comment: Yeah, goofed up due to this many times. Fortunately one can edit and convert-to-CW.

Comment: +1 for letting me try the same because I wanted to verify that error message :)