# Checkbox state not retained bug is back on Post a Question

Tags: bug, asking-questions, self-answer

[This bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24090/validation-fail-unchecks-wiki-email) is back in a new incarnation (same bug, different checkbox): I recently posted a question along with a self-answer. I wanted to post the answer as a CW, so I ticked the **Community wiki** box. Then I clicked **Post your Question and Answer** and it warned me I was trying to create a new tag (I'd added a hyphen to a tag that it doesn't have). I fixed that and posted, and noticed that the answer wasn't a CW.

I tested that here on MSE and noted that if your post doesn't go through because of a warning or error, the **Community wiki** checkbox becomes unchecked again. It should retain its status.

Looks like when the self-answer stuff was added, the old logic handling the old (no longer present) checkboxes wasn't done.